# Set Spring bootstrap.yaml values programmatically

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I would like to set `bootstrap.yaml` property `aws.paramstore.prefix` programmatically.

According to the [documentation](https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-static/spring-cloud-aws/2.0.0.RELEASE/multi/multi__cloud_environment.html#_integrating_your_spring_cloud_application_with_the_aws_parameter_store) the only way to configure it is via `bootstrap.yaml` file. And it works fine if I define `aws.paramstore.prefix` in the `bootstrap.yaml` file. However, I would like to do that programmatically.

There is also a possibility to [customize bootstrap property sources](https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-commons/multi/multi__spring_cloud_context_application_context_services.html#customizing-bootstrap-property-sources), however this does not solve the problem. Custom Bootstrap seem to be loaded later than `aws.paramstore` properties.

As far as I can see the `aws.paramstore` properties are loaded very early on using `spring.factories` that are defined in `spring-cloud-starter-aws-parameter-store-config` dependency:

```
org.springframework.cloud.bootstrap.BootstrapConfiguration=\
org.springframework.cloud.aws.autoconfigure.paramstore.AwsParamStoreBootstrapConfiguration
```

And in `AwsParamStoreBootstrapConfiguration` constructor `AwsParamStoreProperties` is passed as an argument, which is instantiated via `@ConfigurationProperties`. That is `aws.paramstore` are loaded very early on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A hacky workaround is to set the `aws.paramstore.prefix` property before calling `SpringApplication#run` method.

Say we want to set `aws.paramstore.prefix` to the value of a Spring profile that is being passed to the application. Then one can do something like:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // or System.getenv("SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE")
        // or some additional logic that filters a profile that is being passed to the application
        // note that application can also have multiple profiles
        String activeProfile = System.getProperty("spring.profiles.active");
        System.setProperty("aws.paramstore.prefix", activeProfile);

        SpringApplication.run(MyApplication.class, args);
    }
```

In this way we "guarantee" that `aws.paramstore.prefix` is available before ane bootstraps from `spring.factories` kicks in.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to look into PostProcessors that executed on the very first stages of Spring Context initialization. For example, EnvironmentPostProcessor. It executes quite early and probably can help you to manage some properties/modify files before they will be loaded to context.

Note: if you want to use this code in some library that will be a part of another project, you should add such PostProcessor to spring.factories file. In other case it won't be added to configuration stage of another Spring.